# Python numpy polynomial fit: How to draw region of uncertainty curve?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have data that I fit a curve to but which I want to also draw the points, the polynomial through the points; but also a "region of uncertainty" around the fitted line - if it were a 0 degree polynomial it would best be a ~/- standard deviation area coloured around the mean line.

I can do the polyfit and basic graph. Any help with the area calculation and plotting would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I calculated the standard deviation using

```
sdev = sqrt(sum((y - np.polyval(fit, x))**2)/(len(y) - 1))
```

Then:
    def curve(x):
        return np.polyval(fit, x)

```
def sdev_area_mn(x):
    return np.polyval(fit, x) - sdev
def sdev_area_mx(x):
    return np.polyval(fit, x) + sdev
```

followed by:
    fill_between(xfit, sdev_area_mn(xfit), sdev_area_mx(xfit), alpha=0.25, color='r')

And used it for degree 0 and 1 polynomials.